# PDO large insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a large textfile with rows of data that need to be imported in the database. But the file contains like 300000 rows and I can't get it to work, because the query seems too big.

```
$all_inserts    = array();
$count          = 0;
foreach($file as $line) {
    if($count > 0) {
        $modelnummer    = trim(substr($line, 0, 4));
        $datum          = trim(substr($line, 4, 8));
        $acc_nummer     = trim(substr($line, 12, 4));
        $acc_volgnr     = trim(substr($line, 16, 1));
        $prijs          = trim(substr($line, 17,5));
        $mutatiecode    = trim(substr($line, 22,1));
        $all_inserts[] = array($modelnummer, $datum, $acc_nummer, $acc_volgnr, $prijs, $this->quote($mutatiecode));
    }
    $count++;
}
$query = 'INSERT INTO accessoire_model_brommer (modelnummer, datum, acc_nummer, acc_volgnr, prijs, mutatiecode) VALUES ';
$rows  = array();
foreach($all_inserts as $one_insert) {
    $rows[] = '(' . implode(',', $one_insert) . ')';
}
$query .= ' ' . implode(',', $rows);
$db->query($query);
```

I used above code for smaller files and it works fine and fast. But it doesn't work for the bigger files. Does someone know a better way to read and insert this file?

Also tried to use an insert statement per row within a transaction, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: _I can't get it to work, because the query seems too big._ is not specific enough. Why does it not work? What happens? Do you get a error? Does some of the elements get inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I don't know the exact limitations of PDO or SQL for query length*

If the query seems too big, perhaps you could splice up the textfile, so instead of running 1 query with 300k values, run 100 queries with 3000 values i.e.?

Perhaps you could create a buffer, fill it with 3000 values and run the query. Empty the buffer, fill it with the next 3000 values and run the query again.

Comment: Thanks. I've split it to like 5000 at a time and it works now.